# How to properly dismiss UIAlertController both by button and tapping outside?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I'm well aware that similar questions exist yet i think i've failed to see a proper solution for this issue.

If you could  just look at below code, you may say there's nothing wrong with it. BUT,

If i'm going to display a UIAlertController on a UIViewController which is called from storyboard by following code, using button of alert controller dismisses first UIAlertController then my UIViewController. So i navigate back to my initial view controller.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
[vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

And here's the code for UIAlertController:

```
- (IBAction)myAlertAction:(id)sender {
    UIAlertController *controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                                        message:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
                                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];

    [controller addAction:alertAction];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{
        controller.view.superview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [controller.view.superview addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(alertControllerBackgroundTapped)]];
    }];

}

- (void)alertControllerBackgroundTapped
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES
                             completion: nil];
}
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: UIAlertController *controller declare this globlly and then perform your operation

Comment: your code is right . you no need to declare  UIAlertController *controller globally. there are other issue in your code.

Comment: @balkaransingh i beg to differ. i just opened up another project in xcode and test it again. The result is same

Comment: @TimurAykutYILDIRIM i try your code it's work fine.

Comment: @balkaransingh Then perhaps you would like to try this one as well?  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-cDfWHidgvcb3pjdjNpZEpWZ1k

Comment: it's working i test malert.

Comment: @balkaransingh so when you press OK button of alert controller, did it stay in the gray viewcontroller? I need it to stay in gray viewcontroller. But in my computer it goes back to white viewcontroller

Comment: it stay in the gray viewcontroller.

Comment: How is this even possible? It goes back to white vc.

I'm on MacBook Pro (Early 2015) with OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 and I'm using Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175) and i use iPhone 6s plus on my simulator

Answer (score 1):

```
  UIAlertController *controller;


- (IBAction)Btn_alert:(id)sender {
    controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                     message:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              {
                                  //Do some thing here
                                  [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                   [self.presentedViewController presentingViewController];
                              }];

    [controller addAction:alertAction];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{
        controller.view.superview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [controller.view.superview addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(alertControllerBackgroundTapped)]];
    }];
}

- (void)alertControllerBackgroundTapped
{
       [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: i'm afraid nothing has changed

Comment: i just make it one demo and in this demo its completely working . what kind of issue you face

Comment: Imagine you have an app that displays various car names on tableVC and specs of each car in detailVC. And you called detailVC like the first code i shared in question.
---
Now in detailVC there is a button that displays a UIAlertController. With this code if i touch outside of UIAlertController it's fine BUT if i dismiss it by clicking button that comes inside of alertcontroller, it closes both alert and current viewcontroller. So i'm navigated back to tableVC

Comment: I'm using Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175) on OS X 10.11.6

Comment: Then when its dismiss at that time write line  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; its navigate to your tableview controller

Comment: I'm afraid i couldn't understand you well. Should i change the line in alertControllerBackgroundTapped method with your code?

Comment: To make my trouble clear, you could download this demo project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-cDfWHidgvcb3pjdjNpZEpWZ1k

Comment: wait i will check your demo

Comment: @TimurAykutYILDIRIM i just update my answer check it

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/buerwwxyjwmwslw/AAABhm2Hf2yHH65Cvj0IS7M7a?dl=0 check here

Comment: this is really frustrating. I downloaded you code from dropbox and it goes back to white vc too. I just need it to stay in gray vc

Comment: Then comment  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; line it will be stay on that particular controller

Comment: if i comment it. i can dismiss alertController only by clicking the button. I keep that line so that i can dismiss alertController by clicking outside of alertController as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126116/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-timur-aykut-yildirim).

Comment: @TimurAykutYILDIRIM now check it

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ob5jxbis1gn4mfv/AAB75YRAURoNsPdC0AtTjzE3a?dl=0 open this project and run it

Comment: It works properly at first couple of times. But then it starts to broke and goes back to white viewcontroller again :D But thanks for your help, i really appreciate it

Comment: @TimurAykutYILDIRIM still have issue sorry some time its not change and some time its change